# Conflicting types for function in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors, stack

I have written a pop function that pops a linked list stack of character operators (+, *, - , /) and returns the value popped. The problem is I am getting a "conflicting types error". And I can't seem to figure out whats wrong. My linkedCharStack struct is declared as:

```
typedef struct linkedcharStack
{
char elem;
struct linkedcharStack* next;
};
```

The head of the stack is declared in another function outside of pop(not global but pointer) as:

```
struct linkedcharStack * opstack = malloc(sizeof(struct linkedStack));
```

And my actual pop function is:

```
char poptheop(struct linkedcharStack* s1){
struct linkedcharStack* temp;
if(s1==NULL){
    printf("NULL TOP ON POP VALUE STACK!");

}
char returnvalue = s1->elem;
temp = s1;
s1 = s1->next;
free(temp);
return returnvalue;
}
```

Comment: What line are you getting the error on?

Comment: char poptheop(struct linkedcharStack* s1){

Comment: perhaps you should exit the function if `s1 == NULL`

Comment: Do you have another declaration of poptheop somewhere?

Comment: is it a runtime error or compile error?

Comment: Yes. Perhaps that is the problem, I will check that function. it is in another function called as poptheop(*s2);, where *s2 is the character stack. And this is a compile error(As in I try to compile and I get an error).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: I am confused about your variable types. You use `typedef struct linkedcharStack` but I do not see the replacement variable type. A `typedef` statement is: `typedef <actual data type> <replacement name>` so there should be a type in between the `}` and the semicolon.

Additionally, you malloc'd with `sizeof(struct linkedStack)`, but is `struct linkedStack` and `struct linkedcharStack` the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the compile error, i can see a problem in your code:
You are not correctly implementing poptheop, because the change you are doing to the s1 pointer will not be reported to the caller. What you shoould do is pass a pointer to that pointer:

```
char poptheop(struct linkedcharStack** s1){
    struct linkedcharStack* temp;
    if(s1==NULL){
        printf("NULL TOP ON POP VALUE STACK!");
    }
    char returnvalue = (*s1)->elem;
    temp = *s1;
    *s1 = temp->next;
    free(temp);
    return returnvalue;
}
```

You need to do it this way, otherwise your top of stack will not be modified after you pop.

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what someone told me to do when I call this function but I forgot! I just have a question. Why does the parameter need to be a pointer to pointer, but for example *s1 is only a pointer to the struct in the actual function.

Comment: in the caller, you hold a pointer to top-of-stack. Your pop operation should 1) provide the top element (returnvalue) and ALSO 2) remove that element, which means advance the top of stack. in order for the function to be able to modify the top-of-stack parameter, you need to pass a pointer to it, not a copy of its value

Comment: Remember: to have a function change a variable, you pass it a pointer to the variable as parameter. To have it change a pointer, you pass it a pointer-to- the-pointer ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's more general and may be easier to understand/use if we split into two structs: one for stack control and another for elements in that stack:

```
// stack element
struct _stackelem;
typedef struct _stackelem elem_t;
struct _stackelem {
    elem_t *prev;
    elem_t *next;

    char elem;
    int precedence;
};

// stack control
struct _stack;
typedef struct _stack stack_t;
struct _stack {
    elem_t *head;
    elem_t *tail;
    long maxcnt;
    long curcnt;
};

stack_t opStack;

other_func()
{

    opStack.tail = malloc(sizeof(elem_t));
}
```

Note that I've added a "head" to the stack control and "prev" to elem_t.  This allows the stack_t to be a doubly linked list and can implement a queue in addition to a stack, etc. if desired.  Also, I've added a "precendence" to elem_t--more on that below.

Here's your original function [with corrections similar to A.S.H's]:

```
// RETURNS: -1=empty stack
char
poptheop_original(stack_t *stk)
{
    elem_t *tmp;
    char retval;

    tmp = stk->tail;

    // stack is empty
    if (tmp == NULL)
        retval = -1;

    // pop last element
    else {
        retval = tmp->elem;
        stk->tail = tmp->next;
        free(tmp);
    }

    return retval;
}
```

Now, "(*s1)" has been replaced with "stk->tail".  We've avoided passing "**" and the code will execute just as fast.

But, if all you're ever going to need is "elem", I'd consider reimplementing your op stack as just a reallocable array (e.g. "char *opstack").

Using the linked list approach is more suitable for returning more complex stuff.  That's why I added "precedence".  Here's your original function tweaked so you can get at both "elem" and "precedence":

```
// RETURNS: elem is -1 on empty stack
elem_t
poptheop_struct(stack_t *stk)
{
    elem_t *tmp;
    elem_t retval;

    tmp = stk->tail;

    // stack is empty
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        retval.elem = -1;
        retval.precedence = -1;
    }

    // pop last element
    else {
        retval = *tmp;
        stk->tail = tmp->next;
        free(tmp);
    }

    return retval;
}
```

Note that this function still does the "free" internally.  But, it's passing the struct back by *value*.  Almost never a good thing.

Here's the final version where it returns a pointer to the popped elem_t:

```
// RETURNS: NULL is empty
elem_t *
poptheop_pointer(stack_t *stk)
{
    elem_t *retval;

    retval = stk->tail;

    // pop stack
    if (retval != NULL)
        stk->tail = retval->next;

    return retval;
}
```

You now have to free the pointer on your own--that's the downside.  But the upside is that elem_t can have many data elements, not just elem and precedence and will execute quickly with no needless extra data copying.

A further benefit of splitting out stack_t is that you can hide the details of how the stack is implemented.  It could be a singly linked list [as you've done], a doubly linked list, or the realloc array I spoke of earlier.

If you so desire, as an exercise, reimplement stack_t as a reallocable array.  That's why I added "maxcnt" and "curcnt".  If the array approach turns out to be more suitable, then "prev" and "next" can be eliminated from elem_t altogether.

As a further hint:  you only need to realloc during a push and only if curcnt is about to overflow maxcnt.  Do the the realloc as maxcnt + slop_factor to prevent doing too many realloc's.  This will make it "smart".

This might be the best implementation for you--YMMV